# pip3 points to python 3.8 and jupyter notebook points to python 3.9. Having trouble syncing the two

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

which pip3:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip3
```

python version in notebook:

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version())

3.9.2
```

I want my jupyter notebook to run on python 3.8.

NOTE: I'm intentionally avoiding conda for this exercise.

Comment: How do you launch your notebook?

Comment: When you have multiple versions of Python installed it's better to run pip by the *run module* method. use `python3.9 -m pip ...` for python 3.9, and `python3.8 -m pip ...` for Python 3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jupyter is installed into a particular Python environment like any other Python module.  If Jupyter is running under Python 3.9, then you're running the version of it that was installed by the `pip` in Python 3.9.  It might be installed in the base 3.9 implementation, or it could be installed in a virtual environment that is based on Python 3.9.

If you want a Jupyter that is running under Python 3.8, then you need to run the version of it that is installed under Python 3.8 or a virtual environment based on 3.8.  If no such version exists, then you need to install it using Python 3.8 pip.  Once installed, you need to run that version of it.  You can always do that by specifying the full path to the appropriate `jupyter` binary.  But that is, of course, not ideal...

Which version you get when you run just `jupyter` is a function of your PATH and/or any Python package manager you might be running.  I use `pyenv`, and that tool will set it up so that for the Python version I've chosen to be the current global version, that version's (or virtual environment's) `bin` directory becomes the first Python `bin` directory in my PATH. So if I type `jupyter`, I always run the version that is installed in what `pyenv` has made the current global Python environment.